# How to control the color input of a Sunburst with plotly.graph_objects?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, sunburst-diagram

I would like to have control over the colors of each label in the Sunburst diagram below - when using *plotly.graph_objects* instead of *plotly.express*.

See example from [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/) below:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig =go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=[ "Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parents=["",    "Eve",  "Eve",  "Seth", "Seth", "Eve",  "Eve",  "Awan",  "Eve" ],
    values=[  65,    14,     12,     10,     2,      6,      6,      4,       4],
    branchvalues="total",
))
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would allow accessing and control the markers:

```
import plotly.express as px

greys = px.colors.sequential.Greys
reds = px.colors.sequential.Reds
blues = px.colors.sequential.Blues
greens = px.colors.sequential.Greens
magents = px.colors.sequential.Magenta

fig.data[0].marker.colors = ['', greys[5], reds[5], reds[6], reds[7], 
                             blues[5], greens[5], greens[6], magents[5]]

fig.show()
```

[image]